# Singleton of derived class calling base class function fails why?

Tags: c++, printing, singleton, cortex-m, lpc

So I am working the LPC824 which is a cortex-m0+. I am trying to maintain similarity in code to the arduino and am currently stuck on the serial class. Right now I have a serial class that extends a print class as shown below.

Printer.h

```
class Printer
{
public:
    Printer();
    unsigned int print(char c);
    virtual unsigned int write(char c) = 0;
}
```

Printer.cpp

```
#include "Printer.h"
Printer::Printer()
{
    //Nothing to do yet
}

unsigned int Printer::print(char c)
{
    return write(c);
}
```

Serial.h

```
#include "Printer.h"
class Serial : public Printer
{
public:
    Serial();
    static Serial& Serial0();
    unsigned int begin(/*eventually options*/);
    unsigned int write(char c);
}
```

Serial.cpp

```
#include "Serial.h"
#include "uart.h"
Serial::Serial()
{
    //Nothing to do yet
}

Serial& Serial::Serial0()
{
    static Serial inst;
    return inst;
}

unsigned int Serial::begin(/*eventually options*/)
{
    uart0init(115200, 0x04, 0x00);
}

unsigned int Serial::write(char c)
{
    uart0send(c);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Serial.h"
void main()
{
    Serial::Serial0().begin();
    while(1)
    {
        Serial::Serial0().write('a');
        Serial::Serial0().print('b');
    }
}
```

Calling the write function will print out an 'a'. When I then call be print function, my program hangs. Why can I not call the print function on my singleton but I can call the write function?

Comment: Minor thing (not related to your issue), but `Serial` should have either a virtual dtor or protected one. But for your specific issue, did you try changing the order between `write` and `print` (ex: calling `print` before write)? It might not be an issue with calling a base function but just trying to call `write` twice in a row.

Comment: using the debugger, where does the program *actually* hang?

Comment: I dont have access to a debugger. I have put a gpio function to toggle an out when it enters the write function. If I do the Serial::Serial().write('a') it will toggle the pin. If i do the print, it will not print. So I placed the toggle function up one level in the print right before write is called. It will toggle here but it does not toggle in the write function. Its like its not linked properly